# calligra font - apostrophe position

Tags: fonts

As you can see in the picture, the apostrophe is placed in a WRONG position,
when I use calligra font.

Is there a workaround, or a very similar font which doesn't have such problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[left=2.0in,top=2.0in,bottom=0.0in,papersize={5.96in,9.00in},landscape,twoside=false]{geometry}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}



{\Huge Voil\`{a}, c'est pas beau.}

 \ \\

{\Huge \calligra Voil\`{a}, c'est pas beau.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: i think you may have a problem with any such font.  they're usually very stylized.  apostrophes are more often positioned appropriately for cap height or ascender height than for the x-height, and thus are going to be flying rather high above lowercase letters when, as particularly with this font, there is a huge difference between the x-height and the cap height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's ... odd.

Seems to be an error in the font, you can work around it as below but it should probably be reported to the maintainer.

[image]

(I didn't copy your `\\` useful, it was too painful:-)

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[left=2.0in,top=2.0in,bottom=0.0in,papersize={5.96in,9.00in},landscape,twoside=false]{geometry}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}



{\Huge Voil\`{a}, c'est pas beau.}

 \bigskip

{\Huge \calligra Voil\`{a}, c\raisebox{-1.9ex}{\kern-.35em'\kern.35em}est pas beau.}


\end{document}
```